# Exploding array basing on value

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

i have array built like this

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id_objects' => string '2876' (length=4)
      'room_val' => string '1882840,1882841,1882842' (length=23)
      'date_from' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
      'date_to' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id_objects' => string '2876' (length=4)
      'room_val' => string '3198723,3198724,3198726' (length=23)
      'date_from' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
      'date_to' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
```

What i need to achieve is , to explode 'room_val' but keep rest of the data same , it needs to look like this

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id_objects' => string '2876' (length=4)
      'room_val' => string '1882840' (length=23)
      'date_from' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
      'date_to' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
1 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id_objects' => string '2876' (length=4)
      'room_val' => string '1882841' (length=23)
      'date_from' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
      'date_to' => string '2022-06-22' (length=10)
 
..... rest of array
```

Is it possible?

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Yes.

Comment: :) can you give me a tip how to achieve that?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse on your array of arrays and create a new array that match what you are looking for.

Something like:

```
$myNewArray = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $room_vals = $array['room_val'];
    foreach ($room_vals as $room_val) {
        $newSubArray = $array;
        $newSubArray['room_val'] = $room_val;
        $myNewArray[] = $newSubArray;
    }
}
```